# Integer Gui input for button command in Python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a very simple GUI I am trying to make in which I have a single entry, and a single button. I would like to enter a number in the entry, and then use that number as a variable in the command that my button initiates.

For example, if you enter a 2 and my command was to compute 2+emtry, selecting the button would yield a 4.

I have 2 problems:

1. How to convert the entry into an integer?
2. How to use that integer in the command my button calls.

I am very new to Python. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("150x150")

Lbl1 = Label(root, text="Input a number here:")
Lbl1.pack(side=TOP,padx=5,pady=5)
Entry1 = Entry(root, bd =1)
Entry1.pack(side=TOP,padx=5,pady=5)

def PrintCommand():
    print('I want the number from the entry here')

bttn1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="print command", command = PrintCommand)
bttn1.pack(side = TOP,padx=10,pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value, use the `get` method on the entry. To convert it to an integer you can use the python `int` function:

```
def PrintCommand():
    the_number = int(Entry1.get())
    print(the_number)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if the user enters something that's not a number, `PrintCommand` will log an exception to stderr and otherwise do nothing. (That's not a problem with this answer, which is perfect; it's just something for the OP to think about as a future step—what would be the ideal thing to happen in that case, for his design?)

Answer (score -1):

from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter

In your code, at the top you've imported everything from the Tkinter module, then you imported the Tkinter module itself.

import Tkinter
and
from Tkinter import *
both do the same thing, except with "import Tkinter", you must first put a Tkinter. before any command. So you can remove one of them.

Comment: Wesley, this doesn't answer the question -- you're just commenting on the coding style in the question. While what you write is correct, it isn't useful to solving the problem that was asked about.